# Color issues when forwarding X11 display to Windows

Tags: windows, linux, x11, x11-forwarding

I have an application that plots data, line by line to an X11 display where each line is really comprised of different color pixels.

I do this by mapping a data array to an `XImage*` using `XCreateImage`. Then as the data is processed, I populate an `XColor` variables with the red, green, and blue values and call `XAllocColor` to allocate the color. Then I assign the pixel value to the corresponding element in the data array. When all the data is setup, I plot the line using `XPutImage`.

When running the displays on Linux, everything looks great, exactly as expected. However, when I forward the X11 display onto Windows via ssh, the colors are all messed up.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

If I do not use `XCreateImage` and `XPutImage` and create a `GC` with the forground color I want, and use `XDrawPoint`, it works just fine. Seems to be an issue with `XImage` or the issue is overcome automatically when using a `GC`.

Comment: Would you say that your image looks something like the 'incorrect color palette' example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color#Disadvantages)?

Comment: No, not an indexing problem as far as I can tell. The colormap is full 32-bit. Also, as far as messed up, only green, blue and black are diplayed, but no red, none at all, not even blended (e.g. no purple either)

Comment: Don't discard the possiblity of a bug in your Windows X server. Maybe try a different X server software to compare.

Comment: Good work finding it :) I suggest writing the solution as an answer and selecting it, so it'll stand out for others in the future.

Comment: I can do it the way I mentioned in my edit, however, that is a pretty big performance hit, so I am trying to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **a** solution. The problem seems to stem from how Windows does colors vs. Linux. Windows stores colors BGR and BGRA where Linux stores colors RGB and ARGB. So, whenever the display is going to Windows, I need to swap the Red and Blue values before calling `XAllocColor` and after, I need to multiply the `pixel` element of the `XColor` by 256 to shift the colors past the alpha component.

There are some problems associated with this:

1. The application cannot tell if the display is rendered on Linux or Windows, so I am using an environment variable for testing
2. This only works for 32-bit screen depths on Windows, ignore the multiply by 256 if the depth is only 24-bit, less than that I don't know

Because of this, I am actually doing the method I suggested in my **Edit** with a few modifications. Mainly, I create a `GC` for each color that I plan on using during initialization, thus I can just look them up as needed, rather than creating them every time. This keeps the performance reasonably on par vs. using an `XImage`.